# As an employer, how can I see a candidate's SO profile from applying through careers?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, users

Maybe I am missing this or it's just not a feature that exists.  It would be nice to have a URL back to a candidate's Stack Overflow profile when they "apply".

Is it somewhere on here?  Maybe through the CV add a new field called "Link your SO profile"?  A lot of times a resume is a bunch of text and it could be true / untrue. It would be nice to verify it via a person's actions (answering / asking questions).

Comment: Its really worth noting that the actions on SO are not representative of someone's experience or skill. Someone could be only active in the tags they're still learning, for instance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the candidate applies with their Stack Overflow (Careers) CV, and they've chosen to display their Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange account(s) on their CV, there's a link back to their SE profile.

To get there, open the application and navigate to "profile":
[image: profile tab of application]

Then scroll down to the "Stack Exchange" section of the profile. Any linked accounts are clickable, and will take you to their profile within the SE network.

[image: linked Stack Exchange account]

We could probably make it more obvious that those are clickable; they don't really look like hyperlinks at the moment.

Those only appear if the candidate has chosen to both link and display those links, though. So if the candidate has decided that they don't want their CV and their Q&A activity linked, or if the job they applied to is through a third-party ATS that we don't integrate with, then those links won't be available to the employer.

Answer (score 39):

Maybe the SE insight into this is that the application process is separate from the SE/SO site(s). In other words, candidates reserve the right to keep their SO profile private from a prospective employer but if they choose to share it, they can do so on their resume.

Personally, a few reasons why I can see a candidate wanting to hide their SO (and SE) profile from a potential employer are:

- Some comments in other SE communities like The Workplace may reveal more than a candidate would like you to know. It doesn't mean it's necessarily malicious, just that it's simply none of your business.
- The fear that an employer will go, "Oh! I see you seem to know a bit about JavaScript from your SO profile. I know we hired you as a Python developer, but we really need a front-end web developer right now so you're it." (*This actually happened to me in a similar scenario*)
- The concern that you'll make some unreasonable expectations, or lack thereof, due to their profile. Think about how many visits SO get's daily; only a *small* fraction of those visits actually includes users that add to the content of the site. Most people just find what they're looking for and move on- and some happen to see that SO has a job application outlet. I've seen some incredibly technical answers from profiles with low reputation; maybe they were just feeling like educating that day.

In other words, you don't need their SO profile to make an accurate judgement of the candidate. If anything, it may just provide a red herring to the overall perception of the candidate's ability (consider that not every good answer came straight from the author's mind; Google makes people appear to have a larger neural-database than they actually have).

Comment: This is pretty reasonable - I can understand...but it sure would be nice.  Resumes are resumes and I've come across so many that simply lie.

Comment: Another important reason to not link a profile would be that the employers reaction could be like "oh, I see you posted all your answers during working hours and not in your spare time? How did you manage to find time for your job? Oh, you didn't? I see..." Would be a valid reason not to hire the person, although the applicant might just be bored in his actual job and that's the reason why he's applying in the first place.

Comment: @fancyPants If Joe is smart and gets his work done, then I don't really care if he writes answers from work.  If potential employers are really concerned about that, then you probably don't want to work there anyway.

Comment: Okay, that's a good point.