# Is your Stack Overflow username submitted to employers?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, privacy

I don't want employers to see my questions and answers on Stack Overflow. Many employers will use this information and your ranking to make value judgments on candidates that are often based on false assumptions. Anything you say can and will be used against you. As an example, if they notice you ask too many questions about a particular topic, they'll assume you're incompetent even though your questions center around very advanced topics.

For this reason, I don't apply for a Stack Overflow job position using my Stack Overflow account. I usually go directly to the employer's site and submit my resume there. Does Stack Overflow Careers have any facilities for protecting my SO identity?

Comment: I think that if you're asking questions on a particular topic (_and these questions are good enough_), that means _you're learning_, and this is good.

Comment: I think you're being paranoid but the obvious solution would be to create two accounts. One for your Stack Overflow profile and a second for your Careers CV.

Comment: What? Paranoia is a strong word. Any employer, even with the best intentions, will at the very least look at your profile and make a judgment on it, Have you ever employed anyone? I have and understand what is involved. There are lots of temptation to misjudge on insignificant things, especially when money is at stake. Paranoia is more suitable if they went through a lot of effort to gather information, but with the internet it is easier than ordering a pizza.

Comment: @RossRidge, Creating another profile tells them that you are not an active participant which can also be frowned upon.

Comment: If you don't want people to see your actions on a public website, I can't help suggest **not using that website**.

Comment: Not being seen as an active participant of Stack Overflow is what you're asking for. You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @cat, duh! That"s what I am doing now. I want to easily repond to employers without the side effects.

Comment: imho asking a lot of questions is not a problem. neither is asking questions about "simple" problems. What you will get judged by is HOW you ask the questions. Are they well thought and show effort, or are they sloppy / written in haste? It shows character which in many cases is much more important than your skill level.

Comment: @jgauffin  That's how you judge, not how everyone does. Regardless, an employer can use just about any info they view against you,

Comment: Related answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319510/189134

Comment: Seriously, do you really want to work on an employer who "assumes you're incompetent, even though your questions center around very advanced topics". And I am not sure that such employers will post their job openings on SO.

Comment: Another employer's perspective (though I don't use CV for hiring) - yes, we check your online identity. We want to make sure we're not hiring someone toxic and/or lazy. The safest thing is to assume that, if you post it online, your potential employer *will* find it. Simple solution: make sure that you don't give them any good reason to turn you down based on your online conduct. All that said, yes, some employers are jerks that will misinterpret perfectly good questions/answers/comments on StackOverflow, but on that note, would one really want to work for someone like that?

Comment: Why is this a feature request? What're you requesting? Seems like it should be support.

Comment: I'm laughing so hard. When I first posted this question, it was voted down and had a bunch of close requests. It shows that the wisdom of the crowd can sometimes work in your favor.

Answer (score 52):

The Stack Overflow CV is 100% under your control. If you don't want an employer to see your SO username or questions, you can remove them from your CV.

The other option is to apply without using your Stack Overflow CV and just upload a standard CV. We do not pass on your SO details to an employer without your permission (I.E. never unless you've added it to your CV and either chosen to be searchable in our candidate database or used your CV to apply to a job).

Comment: *Warning:* It may seem obvious, but I've seen several applicants do it.  If you include any of your top-answers in your CV, the employers will obviously be able to see your user profile from there, even when you don't include the link to your profile directly in your CV.

Comment: What top answers?

Comment: @user148298 The top answers that you've written on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user148298 Exactly, you can choose to include any of your proudest questions or answers from any of the SE sites as links on your Careers CV.  If they view those, they'll obviously see your user tagline on the post.

Comment: I applied for a Developer job using 'Developer Jobs' section, but I have not included my Stackoverflow profile in the CV that I attached. Will the employer still be able to see my profile, since I was logged in when I applied?

Comment: Is this policy formalized anywhere?

Comment: I reposted this question as it has become old and this answer is no longer true.  You're profile is made available to the employer.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373860/how-do-i-hide-my-profile-so-employers-dont-rummage-through-my-so-activities?noredirect=1#comment629087_373860