# How do I hide my profile so employers don't rummage through my SO activities?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, privacy

There's quite a few people out there who are quite comfortable with exposing their innards to the world, but there are also quite a few and possibly larger group of people who don't want individuals, businesses or institutions rummaging through our online history.  For this reason, I normally bypass SO application forms and apply directly.  Sadly, SO's application process is simple and fast without being hazed with online tests and competency testing.

Having been in the position of employing people in the past for small and large corporations, the hiring process is highly fraught with the most intense form of discrimination imaginable. Even the most minor blemish is magnified when considering a person for a position, especially for a high stakes one. I've always thought of myself as an open-minded and fair person, but I've caught myself too many times rejecting excellent candidates for the most trivial of reasons.

Without getting into too many details, an SO user's profile is a treasure trove for finding such rejections. Enough data can be gathered from a profile and reading through their discussions to form an opinion about someone, even if the activities were strictly professional. As an example, asking for help can be seen as a negative in the eyes of a non-technical hiring manager who may conclude the candidate is inexperienced. Simple grammatical or spelling errors can also hurt a candidate's chances, even though another user edited your Q/A and botched your literary masterpiece.

Perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree here, but I've always had the impression that SO looks out for the best interest of its user base. I hope my simple request isn't met with scorn or ridicule, but productive discourse, especially after the revelations of Facebook and other online organizations.

Comment: 'SO kooks out for the best interest of the developer community' - I'm guessing that's a typo, (but it could go either way).

Comment: If you type personal stuff into the SO interwebz profile, you are essentially broadcasting it. Once it's out, it's out forever.

Comment: LOL!  That wasn't a freudian slip.  Honestly.

Comment: I am not talking about personal stuff, but seemingly innocuous data that can and will be used against you. For instance, an employer could look at your profile and think this guy likes to toy around with prehistoric editors. He is probably one of those UNIX types and will complain about our Visual Studio.  Furthermore, he will probably demand to bring in his loud mechanical keyboard and keep us from getting any work done.  Yeah, we don't want those types in our shop.

Comment: @ATL_DEV: Eliminating managers who are so hypersensitive from your job search is doing you a favor.  Ok, it doesn't seem that way when you desperately need a job, but finding out the company culture is a really poor fit just wastes everyone's time (although it does keep the IPS and Workplace SE question feeds nicely supplied)

Comment: Don't use your real name in your profile?

Comment: So you’d reject my CV because I sometimes make spelling mistakes? I’m not a native speaker of English, so you’ll find a fair few! I must say that if any company is going to be sensitive to that agree I’m *glad* to not be considered by them, saves us *both* some time.

Comment: It looks like that you're already not using your real name on the profile, so nobody knows who the profile belongs to. What's the problem? I don't understand.

Comment: @user202729 I think they want to be able to apply to jobs on Stack Overflow without the employer seeing their Stack Overflow profile. This is a guess: I've never used it but I thought the Jobs site uses your real anyway (or whatever name you give it).

Comment: @BSMP  You are correct.  Once someone sees your resume along with your SO profile name, it's obvious.

Comment: (2 years ago you posted [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321394/is-your-stack-overflow-username-submitted-to-employers), right? ...)

Comment: @user202729.  Yes, I did.  The selected answer is no longer correct.  SO currently states explicitly that employers can access your profile if you submit your CV.

Comment: "Sadly, SO's application process is simple and fast without being hazed with online tests and competency testing." Why sadly?

Comment: You do realize that the reason for SO's application process to be simpler ("without being hazed with online tests and competency testing") is precisely because the employer can see your profile, right? Tests are designed so that the employer can form an opinion of your skills; your SO profile is simply even better for that assessment.

Comment: _"[...] but I've caught myself too many times rejecting excellent candidates for the most trivial of reasons."_  so it simply means that **You shouldn't have ever been a hiring manager in the first place.**

Comment: Is this question specifically focused at the tie-in between stack overflow jobs and users profiles, or more general profile->real world connection?

Comment: @iankemp Sadly, because it means they can't find something just as good that isn't tied to their profile.

Comment: My SO and LinkedIn presence has never hurt me.  In fact, it's impressed folks from time to time..  If you're worried about it, then do some SO gardening once in a while and clean up your questions and answers.  Anybody who refuses to hire on the basis you mention is going to be a very unpleasant person to work for anyway.  Unless you're very early in your career, fuhgeddaboudit!

Comment: *"I hope my simple request isn't met with scorn or ridicule"* - I'm not sure, exactly *what* you are requesting, though. Disassociate your SO Jobs applications from your user account? Provide an option to anonymize your contributions to SO entirely? Something else? May want to make that clearer.

Comment: First of all, no employer is going to know you are ATL_DEV  unless you tell them. Secondly unless you have been doing thing that you are ashamed of you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: You should know that others have their rights to view every comment/activities of you on SO.It's easy for you to make your choice but not others.If you don't want others rummage through you then just remove your everything on SO and never take part of it. As Confucius said : The sage always are open and aboveboard. Don't be narrow inside.

Comment: @AntiMoron,  Sorry, but what you just said makes no sense.

Comment: _"I've always had the impression that SO looks out for the best interest of its user base"_ Heh.

Comment: @ATL_DEV It certainly makes sense.

Answer (score 79):

Having a Stack Overflow profile, or any other online presence for that matter, is a two-edged sword - you get the opportunity to showcase your skills and knowledge, but are also showcasing all the mistakes you make.

I don't think it's Stack Overflow's responsibility to block this - and frankly, I'm don't even think they can. In a nutshell, you're responsible for your own profile.
Are you afraid that potential employers won't want to hire you because they picked up spelling mistakes in your answers? Take an extra few minutes to proofread them.
Are you afraid potential employers won't want to hire you because of technical mistakes in your posts? Make the extra effort to research your answers, or avoid answering if you aren't sure.
 
Are you afraid that potential employers may not want to hire you since you're "asking too many questions"? Don't ask questions on Stack Overflow.

In short - you can't have it both ways. You can't hope to impress a potential employer with reputation points and shiny badges but expect them to overlook spelling mistakes and other less proud moments.

And frankly, if I were in your shoes, I wouldn't worry about that so much. If you are qualified for a position and didn't get it just because you made a typo on a Stack Overflow post a couple of years ago, chances are you don't really want to work there anyway.

Comment: is leading by example here, with a typo in the third word ;)

Comment: @Flimm exactly :-) I try my best, but frankly, mistakes happen. When I (or in this case - you) notice them I try to fix them, but I don't lose any sleep about it.

Comment: Just to explicitly add a last consideration: Do you think that your prospective employer is absolutely wrong to discard you for [thing about your post history]? Then be lucky that you won't need to work for an employer who discards applicants for what you consider to be an unjustified reason.

Comment: There's also the, "Don't identify your profile with any system so that your employer can connect the two," strategy.

Comment: Nobody's really addressing this, but maybe you're right about your SO profile itself-- but what about linked accounts elsewhere on the StackExchange network? Maybe you posted on the politics StackExchange, and the potential hiring manager holds diametrically opposite political views, even though your political views shouldn't ever been considered for e.g. a programming job.

Comment: @C.Helling The system actually addresses this already. When you edit your profile, there's a "Hide Communities" option which allows you to hide connected accounts in other sites you'd rather a potential employer won't see.

Comment: @Mureinik That's a good point, however, I tested this just now by hiding my "Politics" profile, and now it's simply one-click away via the "Network Profile" link.

Comment: @C.Helling interesting. I was not aware of that. I wonder if it's a caching issue, or really a bug.

Comment: I followed up with [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315330/223467) on MSE. Let's see what the devs think about it.

Answer (score 37):

The problem here seems not strictly related to SO itself. Your profile can show your growth and from an employer point of view it can be reassuring to see that you improved your skills constantly as time went through.

As an employer, I would also be very suspicious about a path without mistakes or embarrassing moments, and this brings me to my point: it's unhealthy for you to be worried about having an immaculate look, because is far from the real world.

The only thing I would only worry about is if your SO profile shows that as time pass, you are always at the same skill level, doing the same mistakes.

Comment: Thank you.  You just added another example. If someone appears to not progress as a programmer, it doesn't mean anything.  I frequently find myself searching for the same solutions to problems I had solved years ago. Why?  Because it's hard to keep track of all the minor details especially if you're a programmer who switches across many languages, platforms and domains in different projects.

Comment: I disagree. As a programmer progresses, their ability to adapt to new syntaxes should increase. And even with language switching, most of the simple answers should exist in documentation and questions previously asked by others. If a seasoned developer (even one who switches languages) is constantly asking "newb" questions, it suggest a lack of ability to Read The Fine Manual, which is a characteristic worth screening for. There is nothing wrong with questions, but the quality of question should increase over time, despite the language in the question context.

Answer (score 25):

I'm going to throw out some random things that have come up in conversations I've had with people about this. It's one of the more frequent things folks bring up when they have an opportunity to chat with me at events and conferences.

#### Interviewing is a two-way street.

How an employer looks at your history *is testimony* to how they'll treat you. Read that out loud if it didn't sink in fully, because it's very important to know this. If they will nit-pick through the finest of details of you honing your craft or even crudely increasing its breadth (like diving head-first into a new language), then you probably won't like how they nit-pick your work on the job.

Additionally, look out for being generalized through a tiny glimpse of who you are. Stack Overflow says *some* of what's important to know about you when it comes to who they're gonna hire, it's in no way a full picture, and I'd be wary of anyone that didn't know that.

#### It's one source of possible signal.

What if you *don't* have a lot of stuff on the site, or badges, or rep? What if you don't *have* this magical thing they keep calling  spare time, and would rather spend what time you've got with your loved ones than pushing leaderboards on Github or Stack Overflow?

Be wary of those that think less of you in the absence of an abundance of artifacts of spare time and / or boredom - remember you're interviewing them, too, and that's a red flag about work-life balance expectations.

#### It's supposed to be about growing.

If there's no room for showing what you *were*, then what you *are* somehow seems less significant. We all came from somewhere, we all made mistakes, we all asked basic questions, we all forget to check our tone from time to time - *these are things that indicate that you're a thriving human being*. If someone wants a 'whitewashed' history where you're a machine that just spits out solutions to complicated questions within *minutes* of them being asked, then they probably have some unreal expectations about a level of output that most of us would consider adequate-to-good.

Maybe they read some old books that poorly described what a 'good' programmer looks like, but do you really have time for that? Again, you're interviewing them through how they interview you.

#### And more ...

Lots of good points have come up here. And I can't pretend that I've never been in situations where I took a job I knew I'd hate just because I had no other choice, where I knew *by* how I was interviewed and recruited that I'd be miserable. When you need the money, you need the money. As I was self-taught, SO was my best source of peer-validation, so I was especially happy to show it off (good and bad!). But you might not be. And that's okay.

The way this industry hires is broken and crappy. I like what we're doing in this field, I wish we could do more, and faster, but trying to set new bars for HR and hiring managers and recruiters to *want* to hit takes lots of time.

All I can say is, ***give frank and honest feedback*** when doing so won't harm your immediate goals; that's how companies ultimately rewrite what they know about hiring people. Sure, we do our best to help them succeed on our platform, which means they usually need to change their game around considerably, but they learn from you way more than they learn from us.

But seriously, if a company *really* raised a stink about something in your profile and it *wasn't* you always torturing animals in your example code through variable naming, there's something wrong with their idea of what to look for.

And, well, if you're like me - you probably think stuff about you looks *way* more unflattering than everyone else sees - it's just in our nature.

Comment: "The way this industry hires is broken and crappy. I like what we're doing in this field, I wish we could do more, and faster, but trying to set new bars for HR and hiring managers and recruiters to want to hit takes lots of time." - Tim, could you elaborate a bit on what SO has done to fix this broken industry? I'm aware of Stack Overflow Jobs and the Developer Story, but to me that seems to be a drop in the ocean ATM. I'd love to learn about other initiatives I may be missing.

Comment: @Mureinik Jobs can be a difficult platform for employers to navigate because our developer users don't typically respond well to the usual "HR-style" outreach. A lot of work goes into helping them adapt initially, and then we usually end up spending a lot of time helping them (at least) understand why modernization of practices is critical to get the people that they need. It's way more than I can put in a comment, but employers tend to _learn_ quite a bit on our platform, if only to solidify that traditional practices totally fail when they try them. It is a drop, but it's catching.

Answer (score 9):

The replies of "you probably wouldn't want to work there anyway" are less-than-helpful for those of us who are long-term out of work and have zero right or luxury to be picky about *anything*.

I do wonder sometimes if a JavaScript question I asked years ago has ever cost me employer interest.  It would be nice if there was some way to prevent that.  I like my profile having my work history so I can send that over without having to retype everything, etc., but if I could keep my question history private, to where an employer only knows I asked that stupid JS question if someone *happens* to browse to it, that would be ideal.

Comment: Curious, did you know that you can request that certain contributions be disassociated from your account? What you just said has come up in multiple user interviews. I keep meaning to make that process less onerous and more easy to discover (without _encouraging_ it too much) and always run into an obstacle, thanks for this, it reminds me yet again that we really need to fix that.

Comment: @Janet, you are no newbie when it comes to reality.  As I mentioned in another comment, it is like telling someone who is being harrassed at work to just find another job.  If it were so easy, we wouldn't have employment laws.  I sometimes wonder if the people making these statement ever had to look for work.

Comment: I understand the point you're making here (although I'm not sure I agree with it). What I don't understand is what you'd want SO to do here. Are you suggesting that the answer history is kept public but the question history made private?

Comment: @Mureinik I already explained that at the end of my post: "I could keep my question history private, to where an employer only knows I asked that stupid JS question if someone happens to browse to it, that would be ideal."

Comment: @Janet.  I am suggesting something even better. I want to submit my resume without any association with SO.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of that makes you look bad is using Stack Overflow to do your homework, like some people seem to do. It's dishonest and counterproductive and not what SO is made for.

Another thing is if your questions show you don't understand some fundamental concepts of your trade. But getting hired with fake credentials is short-sighted - if you don't know those fundamental concepts then you're not qualified and will have trouble actually doing the job, so I don't think this is a real problem.

Comment: But Stack Overflow isn't the only site in the network. If you're an awesome developer, but are also an active participant on marxism.stackexchange.com _(not a real site),_ some hiring managers may hold it against you.

Comment: @MikeHarris, bang!!!  You nailed it.  The counter arguments are often like "Well, you wouldn't be happy working for an anti-communist anyway." To me it makes about as much sense as telling someone who is being harrassed to look for another job.  Also, a hiring manager could hate commies, but the actual person who you will work under may actually be a commie.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I think you should edit your question to both clarify that the application process links your real name to your network profile and replace your grammar example with Mike Harris' and your reply. I think it better illustrates your concerns of unfair bias.

Comment: @BSMP.  Great suggestion!  I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of why, you can do this:

In profiles, select <kbd>Edit Profile & Settings</kbd> tab, then look down for 'Hide Communities'.

[image: Screenshot of a small section of a user profile, witha free hand circle around 'Hide Communities']

There are options in there for hiding any of the sites.

Comment: Note that [as discussed below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373865/2422776), these communities will still be visible on your network profile, so this isn't a complete way of hiding activity.

Comment: Yes, this makes it a little harder. All they need is your username and they can search for all your activities.